# How to show value dynamically in vue js wth div

Tags: vue.js, vuesax

showing values from url dynamically, already showing in table correctly, but i want show with div.

```html
<vs-table ref="table" multiple v-model="selected" pagination :max-items="itemsPerPage" :data="products">
  <template slot-scope="{data}">
    <vs-tr :data="row" :key="index" v-for="(row, index) in data">   
      <vs-td>               
        <p>{{data[index].name}}</p>                  
      </vs-td>            
    </vs-tr>        
  </template>
</vs-table>
```

now checking with this div

```html
<template slot-scope="{data}">
 <div v-for="(row1, index1) in data" v-bind:key="row1.id">
   {{data[index1].name}}
 </div>
</template>
```

this div code not working

Comment: Is that `<div>` within the `<template slot-scope="data">` element?

Comment: Please show the context for the code that **isn't** working. Where in your template is that `<div>`?

Comment: I don't know Vuesax but a `<div>` isn't a valid direct-child element within a `<table>`

Comment: i have updated code with my latest code, table code for referrence, im working with div code only

Comment: The [default slot for `vs-table`](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/blob/master/src/components/vsTable/vsTable.vue#L46) is for defining your table rows (`vs-tr` elements **only**). You simply cannot put a `<div>` as a direct child of `<table>`. If you don't want a table, don't use a table

Answer (score 0):

If you are running these both on the same page it might have something to do with your `:keys` being on the same ID. e.g. set the keys with a prefix

```html
<div v-for="(row, index) in data" v-bind:key="'div-'+row.id">
   {{data[index].name}}
</div>
```

Comment: The `key` attribute doesn't need to be globally unique. Only the value should be unique for the `v-for` iterable

Comment: Please provide proof or documentation Phil, `[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '5'. This may cause an update error.`

Comment: You only get that warning if the values used in your `key` attribute are not unique for each item in the `v-for` iterable. Adding prefixes to the keys won't solve that problem either since you'd still end up with duplicate `div-5` values

Comment: This is because they are wrapped in a different parent. when its a root node e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/cwvpzts3/

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that before. That's a fair point but I really don't think it's the problem OP is seeing